# Why is it that npm install doesn't work on my device and I am unable to view the version details even though I've reinstalled?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

I'm completely new to using Node and am honestly very confused about how this all works. I have installed node and NPM but every time I try to check the version to see if it's installed, it tells me "command not found". I've been at this for almost 2 hours just deleting all the npm/node files and reinstalling but nothing seems to give. Can someone please explain if there is anything I can do to fix this issue?

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

If I go inside the NPM file through the terminal, it shows me this when I try to run npm install or npm start.

```
> npm start
npm should be run outside of the Node.js REPL, in your normal shell.
(Press Ctrl+D to exit.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add npm to your path (environment variable on windows not sur on linux) if you are using a portable version, if you are using an installed version of node, it should add npm to your path automatically on windows, not sure on linux, npm start will run the start script from your project package.json file. try going into your npm executable folder (generally in node installation folder), n do a ./npm i -g npm

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified this but I already added it to my path but it still doesn't work.

Comment: npm -v doesn t work outside your npm executable folder? are you on linux?

Comment: No I am using mac

Comment: can you  try a  ./npm i -g npm from npm executable folder?